# PropertyNotFoundException while iterating arraylist in jstl

Tags: jsp, servlets, arraylist, jstl

I have an arraylist in servlet which i am using it in jsp.

```
ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
list = (ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("iInfoType");
```

I am using jstl to parse the array list

```
<c:forEach items="<%=list %>" var="element">    
<c:out value="${element[10].id}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

But getting error PropertyNotFoundException. 
what should i do

Comment: Post the complete exception stack trace, and stop using scriptlets. The JSTL uses the JSP EL, not scriptlets. Forget that scriptlets exist. They shouldn't be used for years and years and years. <c:forEach items="${iInfoType}>" var="element"><c:out value="element"/></c:forEach>

Comment: Also, why do you initialize your variable with a new empty list, just before initializing it again with the list stored in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `id` property for `String`, so you need to change your jstl as shown below:

```
<c:forEach items="list" var="element">    
<c:out value="${element}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Also, when you are using `c:forEach`, you are iterating the list, so using `${element}` gives you the elements present in the `list`.

One more point is that if the `list` is already set in the request scope by the servlet/controller, you don't need to use scriptlets as shown above (i.e., you can directly access the `list` like `items="list"`).

If you want to access the `index` of the `list`, you can use `varStatus` as shown below:

```
<c:forEach items="list" var="element" varStatus="myList">    
    <c:out value="${myList.index}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Using scriptlets in your JSP pages is not a best practice, so I suggest not to use them, please look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/servlets-jsp-140445.html) for more details on JSP best practices. I have added the key point below from the link:

> Embedding bits of Java code (or scriptlets) in HTML documents may not
>   be suitable for all HTML content developers, perhaps because they do
>   not know the Java language and don't care to learn its syntax.

Comment: how to access element at specified index?

Comment: So, you don't want to iterate the `list`?

Comment: i want to. but also want to use each element with their index.

Comment: So you want to know the index of the current element?

Comment: no. want to use each index of the list somewhere in the application. so want to use it with index number.

Comment: @javaguy .. how to access the element kept at specified index. say i want to access the element kept at 5th index of the list